# How to use deprecated method in Android oriented multi API levels?

Tags: android, soundpool

Suppose that the `targetSdkVersion` is `x`, and `minSdkVersion` is `y` (`x > y`), and there is a method, which is deprecated in `x`, but the alternative one is not supported in `y`. How to solve this problem?

For example, `new SoundPool(int, int, int)` is deprecated in API level `21`, and the alternative method is to use `SoundPool.Builder`, but `SoundPool.Builder` cannot be used in API level `14`.

How to do in this case?

Comment: Use the deprecated method, at least on the older device versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a runtime check for the OS Version and then use the deprecated method `new SoundPool(int, int, int)` in the older version while in the new one you can use the `SoundPool.Builder`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.<YOUR_VERSION_X>) {
    //use old method
} else {
    //use new method
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a function, that acccepts necassary parameters and outputs `SoundPool` object depending on SDK version:

```
public SoundPool build(int, int, int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        return new SoundPool.Builder()
                //setParameters
                .build();
    } else {
        return new SoundPool(int, int, int);
    }

}
```